# Sunrise/ Sunset - Conversion of seconds to hh:mm

Tags: date-sunrise

I'm building a weather app and I'm fetching weather and other information from openweathermap.org. I would like to get sunrise and sunset information for each of the searched location but I'm not sure how to change the format from seconds into hh:mm

My code is:

document.querySelector("#sunrise").innerHTML = `${ DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(response.data.sys.sunrise) * 1000 }`;

I tried searching online and came with the above but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After you get your `DateTime` from `fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch` function, you can print the format in hh:mm as:

```
DateTime sunrise = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(response.data.sys.sunrise) * 1000 
DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('hh:mm a');
String formatted = formatter.format(sunrise);
```

This code will produce an output like this:

> 10:05 PM

Or it you would want to use 24 our format use `HH:mm` instead of `hh:mm a`

Comment: Thanks so much Ashish! And would you know if it all looks when added to the function? function displayWeather(response) { document.querySelector("#sunrise").innerHTML =........}

Comment: You can use document.querySelector("#sunrise").text = formatted

Comment: Did it work for you?